# how to run suspended goals in prolog with constraints

Tags: prolog, logic, constraint-programming

I am trying to solve a specific problem using prologs constraint solvers, and I'm stuck :D
A more general version of my problem requirement is the like this:

```
:- lib(ic).:- lib(ic).
solve( [A1*X+B1*Y=C1, A2*X+B2*Y=C2] ):-
X::[0..999],
Y::[0..999],
X #\= 0,
Y #\= 0,

A1*X+B1*Y#=C1, % line1
A2*X+B2*Y#=C2. % line2
```

And this is the query/goal I use:

```
solve( [2*X+3*Y=5, 3*X+2*Y=5] ).
```

And the program will compute the values of X and Y (in this case X=1, Y=1 is the solution).
What I am thinking is, what if the number of arguments in the goal/query can vary..in this case, my prolog program needs to have a dynamic suspended goals in place of lines commented with %line1 and %line2..

Question is, how do i make these expressions delayed..? I do not want to hard code these in the problem and think that only two expressions will be passed over through the goal..

Hope the question is clear.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean something like:

```
:- lib(ic).

solve([]).
solve([Eq | Eqs]) :-
        term_variables(Eq, Vars),
        Vars :: [0..999],
        ( foreach(Var, Vars) do Var #\= 0 ),
        Eq  = (Lhs  = Rhs),
        Eq0 = (Lhs #= Rhs),
        call(Eq0),
        solve(Eqs).
```

Note that this is [ECLiPSe-CLP](http://eclipseclp.org/) specific code (the foreach-loop which could be translated to a recursive helper predicate, of course, and the IC library).

Also note that `call(Eq0)` and writing just `Lhs #= Rhs` should have the same effect (afaik). But when the variables in `Lhs #= Rhs` are solver variables, that seems not to the case, at least I encountered such a problem some months ago using `lib(cplex)`.

Comment: thanks for the snippet. I didnot understand this part of code:
Eq0 = (Lhs #=Rhs)
How does this work? Please guide me to suitable material available online so that I can read up more on such coding. Thank You.

Comment: @kallakafar: if you know that the variable can't have value 0, you can set the domain accordingly `Vars::[1..999]` and drop the `foreach` loop. The line `Eq0 = (Lhs #=Rhs)` means that the variable `Eq0` is bound to the goal `(Lhs #=Rhs)`, but the goal is not executed. It is only executed in the next line `call(Eq0)`. The problem with just writing `Lhs#=Rhs` is that with the ic library, only variables are allowed, not complex terms. In your case, `Lhs` will be a term, so you would need to wrap it in `eval/1`: `eval(Lhs)#=Rhs`.

Comment: @kallakafar: the documentation for ECLiPSe can be found online here: http://www.eclipseclp.org/doc/userman/umsroot.html and here: http://www.eclipseclp.org/doc/libman/libman.html. You should have received both manuals with your ECLiPSe enstallation, though. Then there is Helmut Simonis's e-learning course: http://4c.ucc.ie/~hsimonis/ELearning/index.htm and an ECLiPSe tutorial introduction: http://www.eclipseclp.org/doc/tutorial/index.html. Finally, consider asking ECLiPSe specific questions on the user mailing list: https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/eclipse-clp-users